# how to center align the images inside li?

Tags: css, alignment, html-lists, center

Sorry for my silly question as I am new to web dev.

I got a wrapper of 880px and inside that is the code below. i am trying to get all li elements equally spread horizontally within 880px and have everything inside li element center aligned. I try to avoid using margin-right to spread them, as the last li supposed to perfectly aligned to the right. What would be the best css tricks to achieve this. Thanks a ton in advance!

```
    <div id="services">
        <ul>
            <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block"/><p class="ser-tag">Title1</p><p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p></li>
            <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block"/><p class="ser-tag">Title2</p><p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p></li>
            <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block"/><p class="ser-tag">Title3</p><p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p></li>
            <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block"/><p class="ser-tag">Title4</p><p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p></li>
            <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block"/><p class="ser-tag">Title5</p><p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p></li>
            <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block"/><p class="ser-tag">Title6</p><p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use flexbox to layout. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/6r591jba/

Comment: Thanks a lot @Abhitalks Your solution is also working just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `display: inline block` to the li's and `text-align: center;` to center them.
Add width to each li element so they spread.
Add `font-size:0` to the wrapper so the spaces in the HTML do not take up any space.

See full solution:
http://codepen.io/shippin/pen/KWQgoJ

Answer (score 0):

Specify a `width` on the `<li>` elements and then apply a `text-align:center`. Image elements `<img>` are [inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.3) so you don't have to use `margin:auto;` to center align them.

```
<li class="slide" style="position: absolute; display: none; width: 880px; text-align:center;">
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use,

```
#services ul{
   display: flex;
}
#services ul li {
   flex-direction: column;
   justify-content: center;
   flex-grow: 1;
}
```

this will help you please try.

Answer (score 0):

The `li` elements by default don't spread across the whole width, so you have to apply 100% width to them, and then center their contents using `text-align: center;`:

```css
li {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="services">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block" />
      <p class="ser-tag">Title1</p>
      <p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block" />
      <p class="ser-tag">Title2</p>
      <p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block" />
      <p class="ser-tag">Title3</p>
      <p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block" />
      <p class="ser-tag">Title4</p>
      <p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block" />
      <p class="ser-tag">Title5</p>
      <p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p>
    </li>
    <li><img src="images/icon.png" width="104" height="84" alt="" style="display:block" />
      <p class="ser-tag">Title6</p>
      <p class="ser-subtag">subtag1<br>subtag2<br>subtag3</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```